# Json parsed data need to store in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have parsed URL and I got the JSON objects,string values I need to store this into database.
My Question is:

**which is the best way to insert these JSON Objects?**

I am storing each string value.
Is there any other method which is useful?

Comment: Would you like to store these into online database or using SQLite?

Comment: Have you used databaseHandler class extending SQLiteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* store the entire JSON in a big text field, but if you ever want to access the values individually, you need to store them in individual columns.